# file share witness the given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-cluster

Setup so far:
Two physical servers running Windows Server 2012 standard: INF-HV1 and INF-HV2

Each physical server has a guest Windows Server 2012:  INF-N1 under INF-HV1 and INF-N2 under INF-HV2.  INF-N1 and INF-N2 form a 2 node cluster: INF-FC1.

A further physical machine INF-S1 is running Windows Server 2008 SP2 and has a a shared folder INF-W1. The VCO INF-FC1 and Domain Admins both have full control in both share and NTFS permissions.  All machines are in the same domain on the same subnet.

When I try to add a file share witness (both through the GUI and Powershell) it fails with the message:

> "There was a error configuring the file share witness
>   `\\INF-S1\INF-W1`. The given key was not present in the dictionary"

I have tried putting the share on my own machine too (Win8) but to no avail.  The message is the same.  I am new to clustering and may have completely missed something but whatever the reason I am completely stuck.

Comment: Well - I have a workaround that has worked twice. Firstly offline the cluster and do a repair - not sure if that is necessary but others have suggested it can help sometimes.  The key thing for me was to wait (at least 5 mins) before clicking next for the last time during the process of adding the file share majority.  It then seems to manage it!  I Have no idea why, and this is hardly a solution, but perhaps it will be enough to suggest what the problem is to someone else?!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

To solve it, I created my cluster with only one node, then I configured the quorum using these parameters for the FSW:

Domain account has Full Control on the share + NTFS

CNO has Full control on the share + NTFS

Give the FQDN of the target: "\server.XX.ZZZZZ.corp\share

It worked for me.